# PHP-PDO -- echoing db rec into table not working

Tags: html, pdo, insert, html-table, row

I have this problem and it's really simple but just can't think straight, been at too much code.. I'm trying to echo field values from db into table columns, then add these as rows in table.

I was hoping if you can take a look and see whats wrong.

```
<?php
    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
    require("common.php");

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coffee");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //echo $row['field'];
    //echo $row['apples'];
    //echo $row['bananas'];
    //echo $row['cherries'];

    while($row = true){
    $records = "<tr>
                <td>".echo $rec['apples']."</td>
                <td>".echo $rec['bananas']."</td>
                <td>".echo $rec['cherries']."</td>
                </tr>";
    }
?>

<style type="text/css">
table.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #9dcc7a;border-collapse: collapse;}
table.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#abd28e;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;text-align:left;}
table.tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
table.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;}
</style>

<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Apples</th><th>bananas</th><th>Cherries</th></tr>
<? print $records ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I am sorry for disappointing you but a question like this is against rules here.

Comment: oh didn't know. which rule?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><td>Apples</td><td>bananas</td><td>Cherries</td></tr> 
  <?php
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coffee");
$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<tr>
            <td><?=$row['apples']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['bananas']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['cherries']?></td>
            </tr>
<?
}
?>
   </table>
```

Comment: no it didn't work. it gave me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end ... im gonna look into more, ill get back to you soon.